# How to connect laravel with mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have read some tutorials and videos. I just downloaded and installed laravel. Trying to create a simple registration form.

welcome.blade.php

```
<form action="{{URL::to('/store')}}" method="post">
       {{csrf_field()}}
       <input type="text" name="clientFirstname" >
       <input type="text" name="clientSurname" >
       <input type="text" name="clientEmail">
       <input type="hidden" name="token" value="">
       <button type="submit" name="button">add</button>
</form>
```

web.php

```
Route::view('/', 'welcome');
Route::post('/store', "Controller@store");
```

Controller.php

```
class Controller extends BaseController {

    public function store(Request $request) {
        //print_r ($request->input());
        //print_r ($request->input('clientFirstname'));
        $result=DB::insert("INSERT INTO test('firstname', 'surname', 'email') VALUES(?, ?, ?)", $request->input('clientFirstname'), $request->input('clientSurname'), $request->input('clientEmail'));
        echo $result;
    }
}
```

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=testdb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

database.php

```
        'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'testdb'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        ],
```

i have created a db named testdb through phpmyadmin. Let me inform you that I can print the form fields but when i insert code as above that inser to db something i got the following error.

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR) Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type
>   array, string given, called in
>   C:\Users\regor\ExampleProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php
>   on line 665

I would appreciate any help. :)

Comment: There's another issue in your query as well. You should read this post [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

The `DB::insert()` method accepts **an array** as the second argument.

You should use it like this:

```
DB::insert("INSERT INTO test(`firstname`, `surname`, `email`) VALUES(?, ?, ?)", [
    $request->input('clientFirstname'),
    $request->input('clientSurname'),
    $request->input('clientEmail')
]);
```

Also, use back ticks for column identifiers instead of single quotes.

Comment: Corrent. Thank you for your change. :)